# Cannot SELECT FROM declared table in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

In my function declaration :

```
$function$
declare

alllogins schema.EmployeeLogin;
nologins schema.Employee;

begin

SELECT * INTO alllogins FROM schema.EmployeeLogin;
SELECT * INTO nologins FROM schema.Employee AS a WHERE NOT EXISTS 
   (SELECT 1 FROM alllogins WHERE schema.EmployeeId = a.EmployeeId );

end;
$function$;
```

Returns

```
ERROR:  relation "alllogins" does not exist
LINE 1: ...ema.Employee AS a WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM alllogins ...
                                                             ^
```

Which in fact exists, since I have already `SELECT * INTO` it without problems. Why I can do `SELECT INTO` and not `SELECT FROM` ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a PL/pgSQL variable as table name. This is the same as trying to use a prepared statement with a placeholder for a table name, which is not supported. Placeholders and variables can only be used instead of constants.

You will have to use dynamic SQL with the `EXECUTE` command.